# How to declare a var in bash without it replacing a var in a different file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, sh

I have 2 files file1 and file2. Inside file1 I declare a var, x=1. In file2 I make a var x=2. If I run file one then file two, and then in the shell echo x, I get x=2. How would I access the x=1 from file1 when I need to and then access the x=2 from file 2 if I need to.

Comment: If you "run" file1, and then "run" file2, the value of `x` in the original shell is whatever it was before you ran either file.  But I suspect you are using "run" when you mean "source".  If you do `. file1; . file2`, then the value of x is whatever it was set to last. The question is how are you "running" file2?

Answer (score 0):

If you call file2 from file you'd like to export x in file1
It would be something like this:

file1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export x=1
echo "$x from $0"
./file2.sh

echo "$x from $0"
```

file2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
x=2
echo "$x from $0"
```

Output will be

```
$ ./file1.sh 
1 from ./file1.sh
2 from ./file2.sh
1 from ./file1.sh
$
```

If you call *file1.sh* and *file2.sh* separately then *x* must be declared previous to *file1.sh* execution.

In this example *x* is undefined, then it is exported as a global variable, and youc an see its value from the second echo:

```
$ echo $x

$ export x=1
$ echo $x
1
$
```

If lines containing declaration of *x* and call to *file2.sh* are removed form *file1.sh*, then you'll see *file1.sh* inherits the value of *x*. But it is overridden  in *file2.sh*.

Once *file2.sh* execution finishes the  value of x remains 1:

```
$ ./file1.sh 
1 from ./file1.sh
$ ./file2.sh 
2 from ./file2.sh
$ echo $x
1
$
```

You can try exporting x=3 in the shell and using *file1.sh* and *file2.sh* as in first example then you'll see something like this:

```
$ export x=3; echo $x; ./file1.sh ; echo $x
3
1 from ./file1.sh
2 from ./file2.sh
1 from ./file1.sh
3
$
```

Regards

Comment: I am not home now, sorry. But I will try this as soon as I get back and get back to you when I can. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In file2.sh, instead of doing `x=2`, you can write it like `: ${x=2}`.

Demo -

```
# Creating the files
$ echo x=1 > file1.sh
$ echo ': ${x=2}' > file2.sh
# Running both files
$ . file1.sh
$ . file2.sh
$ echo $x
1
# See? the output is 1, which was set by file1.sh
# Now, if you want to get the value of x from file2.sh -
$ unset -v x
$ . file2.sh
$ echo $x
2
# See? the output is 2, which was set by file2.sh
$ . file1.sh
$ echo $x
1
# See? x was over-written by file1.sh
```

Contents of file1.sh in above demo -

```sh
x=1
```

Contents of file2.sh in above demo -

```sh
: ${x=2}
```